# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, library is 64-bit instead of 32-bit

Tags: java, android

Whenever I start an Activity which has an element provided by a 3rd party library I get the following error (only on some devices):

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.*.*/libarchitect.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
```

The provider of the library told me to check if I have any 32-bit native library inside the .jar libraries in my project, how can I tell from a jar file if it uses 64-bit or 32-bit native libraries?

EDIT:

the device where the app crashed is a Samsung Galaxy S5 NEO which is 64-bit

Comment: What is `Activity`? Is it android?

Comment: A jar file doesn't have 32 or 64 bit variations... The error is complaining about the `libarchitect.so` file, which is **native** library... Your device is a 32 bit system, but the library is compiled for 64 bit...

Comment: @Andremoniy sorry I forgot to mention, yes I'm talking about Android, i've added the tag

Comment: @Codebender Sorry the last answer was incorrect, the device where the app crashes is a Samsung galaxy s5 NEO which is 64bit, that's why I can't understand why the problem occurs

Comment: you must add proper native libraries. there should be libraries under `armeabi-v7a\libarchitect.so` , `armeabi\libarchitect.so` and `x86\libarchitect.so`

Comment: @ChathuraWijesinghe the SDK picks the right one based on the CPU used by the device, I've just tried to export every library and import them inside my libs folder this way the device should pick the library from there, the problem is that adding those libraries (4 new folders) results in an increment of the app's weight, am I correct?